# How to update VSCode on Ubuntu -2021

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code

I have VSCode on Xubuntu
I can't seem to figure out how to update VScode, it keeps putting a notification to update at the bottom right but on the 'update' button it just sends a link to the main VScode page (https://code.visualstudio.com/). However I don't know if it just re downloads and if it is incorrectt.
How do you update it correctly?

(I have tried some 'sudo ...' from the internet but they didn't work for me and I wonder if it is because it is outdated)

Thank you

Comment: Maybe go to the download link on the Visual Studio Webpage and download?

Comment: Is it okay to re-download it? I wonder if there is something else that is simply update?

Comment: How did you install it in the first place?

Comment: Through that .deb in the main page (https://code.visualstudio.com/) I'm pretty sure

Comment: Then `sudo apt update` `sudo apt upgrade` should update it.

Comment: This did a whole lot of updates but unfortunately I still get the 'update available' button

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For those who installed through `.deb`

So apparently I needed to setup an apt repository:
You can find instructions on how to add the apt repository here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux#_debian-and-ubuntu-based-distributions

I followed the "Debian and Ubuntu based distributions" chapter and did the alternative method they offered so:

```
wget -qO- https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | gpg --dearmor > packages.microsoft.gpg
sudo install -o root -g root -m 644 packages.microsoft.gpg /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64,arm64,armhf signed-by=/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/packages.microsoft.gpg] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list'
rm -f packages.microsoft.gpg

sudo apt install apt-transport-https
sudo apt update
sudo apt install code
```

And then finally as people have recommended:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

And this time it does update it! :)

(I must have not done this setup when installing .deb)

Answer (score 1):

To update all applications on my machine,

```
sudo apt update
```

For Ubuntu hirsute 21.04, this is not working anymore. To update vscode, run the following commands;

```
sudo apt-get update
```

```
sudo apt-get install code
```